# Build electron tamanho final

Tags: electron

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de gerar um build de uma app eletron em um tamanho inferior a 80 Mbs.
Tentei gerar em diversas plataformas mas sempre fica acima de 121mb
São apenas 10 páginas. Entretanto o electron na pasta node modules baixado pelo npm apresenta mais de 400mb

Comment: Um colega meu conseguiu reduzindo as dependências. Foi um processo manual e doloroso, mas conseguiu. Também teve o caso de gerar multiplataforma; quando gerava para x86 e x86_64, era praticamente feita uma cópia de tudo, no lugar de ter uma parte comum e só um pequeno diferencial para rodar em cada plataforma

Comment: Um issue relacionado https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2003